# Full Text search with Laravel Doctrine and Postgres. Semantic error on using library "jaimz22 / DoctrineFullTextPostrgres"

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

For implementing full text search to my application I found a library " jaimz22 /
DoctrineFullTextPostrgres "

Below are my configurations.

composer.json :

**"vertigolabs/doctrine-full-text-postgres": "1.1.1"**

doctrine.php :

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Entity Managers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Configure your Entity Managers here. You can set a different connection
    | and driver per manager and configure events and filters. Change the
    | paths setting to the appropriate path and replace App namespace
    | by your own namespace.
    |
    | Available meta drivers: fluent|annotations|yaml|simplified_yaml|xml|simplified_xml|config|static_php|php
    |
    | Available connections: mysql|oracle|pgsql|sqlite|sqlsrv
    | (Connections can be configured in the database config)
    |
    | --> Warning: Proxy auto generation should only be enabled in dev!
    |
    */
    'managers'                   => [
        'default' => [
            'dev'           => env('APP_DEBUG', false),
            'meta'          => env('DOCTRINE_METADATA', 'annotations'),
            'connection'    => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
            'namespaces'    => [],
            'paths'         => [
                base_path('app/Entities')
            ],
            'repository'    => Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::class,
            'proxies'       => [
                'namespace'     => false,
                'path'          => storage_path('proxies'),
                'auto_generate' => env('DOCTRINE_PROXY_AUTOGENERATE', false)
            ],
            /*
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            | Doctrine events
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            |
            | The listener array expects the key to be a Doctrine event
            | e.g. Doctrine\ORM\Events::onFlush
            |
            */
            'events'        => [
                'listeners'   => [
                    //VertigoLabs\DoctrineFullTextPostgres\Common\TsVectorSubscriber::ANNOTATION_TSVECTOR,
                ],
                'subscribers' => [
                    //VertigoLabs\DoctrineFullTextPostgres\Common\TsVectorSubscriber::ANNOTATION_TSVECTOR,
                    new VertigoLabs\DoctrineFullTextPostgres\Common\TsVectorSubscriber(),
                ]
            ],
            'filters'       => [],
            /*
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            | Doctrine mapping types
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            |
            | Link a Database Type to a Local Doctrine Type
            |
            | Using 'enum' => 'string' is the same of:
            | $doctrineManager->extendAll(function (\Doctrine\ORM\Configuration $configuration,
            |         \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection $connection,
            |         \Doctrine\Common\EventManager $eventManager) {
            |     $connection->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');
            | });
            |
            | References:
            | http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html
            | http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/types.html#custom-mapping-types
            | http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/advanced-field-value-conversion-using-custom-mapping-types.html
            | http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#reference-mapping-types
            | http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/dbal.html#registering-custom-mapping-types-in-the-schematool
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            */
            'mapping_types' => [
                //'enum' => 'string'
                'tsvector' => 'tsvector'
            ]
        ]
    ],
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Doctrine Extensions
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Enable/disable Doctrine Extensions by adding or removing them from the list
    |
    | If you want to require custom extensions you will have to require
    | laravel-doctrine/extensions in your composer.json
    |
    */
    'extensions'                 => [
        //LaravelDoctrine\ORM\Extensions\TablePrefix\TablePrefixExtension::class,
        //LaravelDoctrine\Extensions\Timestamps\TimestampableExtension::class,
        LaravelDoctrine\Extensions\SoftDeletes\SoftDeleteableExtension::class,
        //LaravelDoctrine\Extensions\Sluggable\SluggableExtension::class,
        //LaravelDoctrine\Extensions\Sortable\SortableExtension::class,
        //LaravelDoctrine\Extensions\Tree\TreeExtension::class,
        //LaravelDoctrine\Extensions\Loggable\LoggableExtension::class,
        //LaravelDoctrine\Extensions\Blameable\BlameableExtension::class,
        //LaravelDoctrine\Extensions\IpTraceable\IpTraceableExtension::class,
        //LaravelDoctrine\Extensions\Translatable\TranslatableExtension::class
    ],
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Doctrine custom types
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Create a custom or override a Doctrine Type
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    'custom_types'               => [
        'encrypted' => App\dbal\Encrypted::class,
        'tsvector' => VertigoLabs\DoctrineFullTextPostgres\DBAL\Types\TsVector::class,
    ],
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | DQL custom datetime functions
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    'custom_datetime_functions'  => [],
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | DQL custom numeric functions
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    'custom_numeric_functions'   => [],
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | DQL custom string functions
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    'custom_string_functions'    => [
        'tsquery' => VertigoLabs\DoctrineFullTextPostgres\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\TsQueryFunction::class,
        'tsplainquery' => VertigoLabs\DoctrineFullTextPostgres\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\TsPlainQueryFunction::class ,
        'tsrank' => VertigoLabs\DoctrineFullTextPostgres\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\TsRankFunction::class,
        'tsrankcd' => VertigoLabs\DoctrineFullTextPostgres\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\TsRankCDFunction::class,

    ],
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register custom hydrators
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    'custom_hydration_modes'     => [
        // e.g. 'hydrationModeName' => MyHydrator::class,
    ],
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Enable query logging with laravel file logging,
    | debugbar, clockwork or an own implementation.
    | Setting it to false, will disable logging
    |
    | Available:
    | - LaravelDoctrine\ORM\Loggers\LaravelDebugbarLogger
    | - LaravelDoctrine\ORM\Loggers\ClockworkLogger
    | - LaravelDoctrine\ORM\Loggers\FileLogger
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    //'logger'                     => env('DOCTRINE_LOGGER', false),
    'logger'=>"LaravelDoctrine\ORM\Loggers\FileLogger",
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cache
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Configure meta-data, query and result caching here.
    | Optionally you can enable second level caching.
    |
    | Available: apc|array|file|memcached|php_file|redis|void
    |
    */
    'cache' => [
        'second_level'     => false,
        'default'          => env('DOCTRINE_CACHE', 'array'),
        'namespace'        => null,
        'metadata'         => [
            'driver'       => env('DOCTRINE_METADATA_CACHE', env('DOCTRINE_CACHE', 'array')),
            'namespace'    => null,
        ],
        'query'            => [
            'driver'       => env('DOCTRINE_QUERY_CACHE', env('DOCTRINE_CACHE', 'array')),
            'namespace'    => null,
        ],
        'result'           => [
            'driver'       => env('DOCTRINE_RESULT_CACHE', env('DOCTRINE_CACHE', 'array')),
            'namespace'    => null,
        ],
    ],
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Gedmo extensions
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Settings for Gedmo extensions
    | If you want to use this you will have to require
    | laravel-doctrine/extensions in your composer.json
    |
    */
    'gedmo'                      => [
        'all_mappings' => false
    ],
    /*
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     | Validation
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |
     |  Enables the Doctrine Presence Verifier for Validation
     |
     */
    'doctrine_presence_verifier' => true,

    /*
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     | Notifications
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |
     |  Doctrine notifications channel
     |
     */
    'notifications'              => [
        'channel' => 'database'
    ]
];
```

Entity :

```
use VertigoLabs\DoctrineFullTextPostgres\ORM\Mapping\TsVector;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity @ORM\Table(name="contact") 
 */
class Contact
{
    use AuditTrait;


    /** @ORM\Id @ORM\Column(type="integer") @ORM\GeneratedValue */
    public $contactId;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string", name="first_name") */
    protected $firstName;

    /**
     * @var TsVector
     * @TsVector(name="firstName_fts", fields={"firstName"})
     */
    private $firstNameFTS;
```

When I try to do schema update it shows Semantic Error. Can someone help me solving this. Thanks in advance.

```
admin1@admin1-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:/var/www/html/crm-php-backend$ php artisan doctrine:schema:update --force

Checking if database connected to default entity manager needs updating...

   Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException  : [Semantical Error] The annotation "@VertigoLabs\DoctrineFullTextPostgres\ORM\Mapping\TsVector" in property App\Entities\Contact::$firstNameFTS was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?

  at /var/www/html/crm-php-backend/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationException.php:39
    35|      * @return AnnotationException
    36|      */
    37|     public static function semanticalError($message)
    38|     {
  > 39|         return new self('[Semantical Error] ' . $message);
    40|     }
    41| 
    42|     /**
    43|      * Creates a new AnnotationException describing an error which occurred during

  Exception trace:

  1   Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException::semanticalError("The annotation "@VertigoLabs\DoctrineFullTextPostgres\ORM\Mapping\TsVector" in property App\Entities\Contact::$firstNameFTS was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?")
      /var/www/html/crm-php-backend/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/DocParser.php:775

  2   Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocParser::Annotation()
      /var/www/html/crm-php-backend/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/DocParser.php:691

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Comment: Start to try with this: Please use the argument -v to see more details

Comment: Thanks. With -v I am getting the following error.  ReflectionException::("Class TsVector does not exist")
      /var/www/html/crm-php-backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:803